# how to remove repeat rectangle from vector<Rect>?

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I have many `Rect rectangle` store in `vector<Rect>`. But it has many repeat rectangle inside. How to remove them? For example:

```
    Point Pt1(267, 83);                 
    Point Pt2(487, 167);
    Rect    rec1(Pt1, Pt2);
    GroundTruthSet.push_back(rec1);


    Point Pt3(257, 90);
    Point Pt4(450, 150);
    Rect    rec2(Pt3, Pt4);
    GroundTruthSet.push_back(rec2);

    Point Pt5(267, 83);                 
    Point Pt6(487, 167);
    Rect    rec3(Pt1, Pt2);
    GroundTruthSet.push_back(rec3);
```

How to remove the repeat rectangle in `vector<Rect>`?

Comment: Store them in a set first and then copy to vector?

Comment: std::sort + std::unique + erase

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique.

Comment: ... assuming that your `Rect` class has sensible equality and comparison operations (if not, implement them!)

Comment: but the vect<Rect> cannot sort.

Comment: @January checkout the example in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: @January Please either accept the answer or update your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [Strict Weak Ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) on `Rect`.  For rectangles, comparing their individual components is enough.

```
auto comp_lt = [](const Rect& lhs, const Rect& rhs) {
    // compare each component in the following lexicographical order
    return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y, lhs.width, lhs.height) <
        std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y, rhs.width, rhs.height);
};
auto comp_eq = [](const Rect& lhs, const Rect& rhs) {
    // `std::unique` uses equality-comparison, not less-than-comparison
    return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y, lhs.width, lhs.height) ==
        std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y, rhs.width, rhs.height);
};

std::sort(std::begin(GroundTruthSet), std::end(GroundTruthSet), comp_lt);
auto pivot = std::unique(std::begin(GroundTruthSet), std::end(GroundTruthSet), comp_eq);
v.erase(pivot, std::end(GroundTruthSet));
```

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique), [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

Comment: You can use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to make the comparison a tiny bit less ugly.

Comment: Since the question tags opencv3 you could change the `(y1, y2, x1, x2)` to `(x, y, width, height)`: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect

Comment: @ilent Thanks, just set it up